# Call click handler without clicking item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some JavaScript/jQuery code that needs to call the checkbox's click handler after it completes.

I can use `trigger()` to call that handler; however, I see that this also causes the checkbox's checked state to toggle (as though it had been clicked).

Is there any way to call a click handler without actually performing a click on the checkbox?

Comment: Can you provide some code? Most probably you might have to do event.preventDefault().

Comment: @yaswanth: But if I do `event.preventDefault()`, wouldn't that prevent toggling the checkbox when the user actually clicks it with the mouse? I still want the checkbox to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to call a click handler without actually performing a click on the checkbox?

Yes

The handler is just a function. Call the function:

```
function example() {
  $(this)...do something...
}

$(...selector...).on('click', example);

...elsewhere...

$(...another selector...).each(example)
```

---

If you don't have a reference to the function, and you want to trigger *all* handlers on the element *without* triggering the native behaviors, you can use jQuery's [`.triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) method.

```
$(...selector...).on('click', function () {...})

...elsewhere...

$(...another selector...).triggerHandler('click')
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something more clever I guess. But you're right. That will work fine.

Comment: @JonathanWood I hadn't finished writing. You probably want `triggerHandler`, although I've never found a case where I've actually wanted `triggerHandler` because calling a named function has always been more appropriate. `triggerHandler` won't stop *other* handlers from being fired, which makes it prone to unintentional consequences.